# How to add custom data table when object is created in pimcore

Tags: php, zend-framework, e-commerce, pimcore

I am using pimcore 4.6. I am newbie to pimcore. When adding new object I need to add the object details into another cust table in sql.

[image: image of object adding page]

I need to add this `catgories` `QuantityType` and `IngredientName` to be saved in a new table in SQL

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take time and visit [SO Asking Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and must read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the same.